# Obtain Lists instead of Arrays in Visual Studio Paste XML as Classes

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2015 Edit...Paste Special...Paste XML as Classes feature, is it possible to obtain those properties that are arrays as Lists instead?  The problem is that it makes it more difficult to add new items to the object.  Even though adding them would still adhere to valid xsd for the xml used.   For example, in the code below obtain List instead of bookPage[]

Reason is that what if these classes represent the settings for my application and what if I'm using a GUI where the settings are stored in memory and the user can change the settings - I want them to also be able to add and remove objects from the collection (i.e. pages)

If this is not possible using this tools, are there any alternative suggestions that would be suitable?

XML

```
<book>
    <page value="1"/>
    <page value="23"/>
</book>
```

CLASSES Generated by Visual Studio (Paste XML as classes feature)

```
 /// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class book
{

    private bookPage[] pageField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("page")]
    public bookPage[] page
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.pageField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class bookPage
{

    private byte valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```